# ntlm Authentication in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ntlm, dynamics-business-central

Trying to connect to Business central web services hosted on a local server.

I managed to get a connection with ntlm auth in postman. I can however not get it to work in javascript.

gives me a 401.

How do I approach this problem? Is it even possible to do in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a Web Service Access key on a user in Business Central. Once you have done that basic authentication will do the trick. The below works in NAV2018.

For more recent versions of BC oauth2 via Azure Active Directory is recommended.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const base64 = require('base-64');

module.exports = async function (url, body) {

    let response = fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + base64.encode(channel.bc_user + ":" + bcPassword),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(body)
    }).then(res => {
        return res;
    });

    return response;
}
```